# Как мне найти элементы первого списка которые НЕ находятся во втором списке

Tags: python

```
from random import randint as rand
print('#2')
list_1 = [rand(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
list_2 = [rand(1, 10) for i in range(10)]

print(f'List_1: {list_1}')
print(f'List_2: {list_2}')

result = list(set(list_1) ^ set(list_2))
print(f'Only in the first are there: {result}')
```

Answer (score 0):

На множествах определена операция `-`, которая делает именно это

```
result = list(set(list_1) - set(list_2))
```

Comment: А не подскажите как вывести числа которые входят как и в первый так и во второй список? Заранее спасибо

Comment: не смог быстро найти толковый док на русском. пересечение множеств `&`

Comment: Код:
```
list_1 = [rand(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
list_2 = [rand(1, 10) for i in range(10)]

print(f'List_1: {list_1}')
print(f'List_2: {list_2}')

result = list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))
print(result.sort())
Консоль:
```
List_1: [8, 9, 5, 4, 1, 8, 8, 6, 7, 10]
List_2: [6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 2, 2, 9, 4, 8]
None
```
Почему None?

Comment: Ха-ха. Извините. Несвязанная проблема - sort сортирует объект, на котором вызван, и ничего не возвращает. Но есть функция sorted: `print(sorted(result))`